# Creating a news site with out-of-the-box web parts?

Tags: web-part, page-layout

In my company we have these periodically released news bulletins. One news bulletin is one html page. Now I am looking for a way to create a decent overview of these bulletins whilst also displaying the last one. I have created a paint image below to show my desires:

[Desired look http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/629/meaning.png](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/629/meaning.png)

Now my question is how I can best achieve this with out of the box functionality in SP 2010. For example, I can let people create pages in the news section, use the page viewer to display them on the left, and a content query to show the archive on the right?

When doing this however I get the ribbon and stuff inside the page viewer and that is not what I want. So I am looking for your opinion on the best way of implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers were useful, however i decided to use the blogging functionality to create a news site. This automatically creates an archive for you and suited all my needs, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the preview pane with some sort of filter already applied to show the most recent post in the main body of the page. You might also consider looking at the way the blog site is designed. This might help you, as it is very similar to the functionality you are looking for. As far as the archive goes, you can either use a list view that is customized or an aggregation tool like either RSS or the Content Query Web Part. All of those are out of the box options that you can use to make your idea work.

Comment: Using the preview pane, I can let it show data from the object but not the object itself, or did i overlook that functionality?

Answer (score 4):

We have external company that create each newsletter sheet like html page with a lot of images and background graphics and the easiest way for us is inserted it like iframe to our pages. Content administrators just easily upload new file, correct link and everybody is happy. Our page is similar to yours, just imagine it colorful, with borders around the text with squares and background pictures behind the text...

[image: newsletter page]

Comment: This looks nice, the problem i am having with the IFrame however is that it also shows the ribbon and navigation in the IFrame, how did you resolve this?

Comment: It depends what you have inserted in page, we have only images, text and links and no ribbon (or any other menu) in there. You can add CEWP and <iframe src=""> without borders to code or CEWP and insert link directly to the part named Page viewer, section web page. I can't give you exact proof, because news page is strictly internal page, but I can make  "fake" and post it here if you want.

Comment: Wauw, if you could do that it would really help me a lot! Because what you have is exactly what i am looking for. In the iframe i redirect to the (.aspx) page that users create. Therefore it shows the ribbon, which i do not desire.

Comment: But I don't have .aspx page and redirect, maybe this is the problem. I have simple CEWP and current_newsletter_folder\index.html page inside. Page with no controls and external company send us new every month. We just switch the links.

Comment: Aaah i see, well what i am trying to achieve is that the user can easilly add another news part. So just click new page and then the magic happens... Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: So if I understand clearly, you need one list of newsletters (on the left column of page, as list for example) and when someone click on "new item", system show some template, that will be after completing  atutomaticaly inserted (maybe after approve) in right column as newsletter page?

Comment: Yes, there will be an archive of news letters in the form of a list. When the user creates a new news letter, i do not knwo in what form, maybe a new page(.aspx) or something else(it has to have text + images an hyperlinks etc.). When the user adds a newsletter it has to be added to the top of the newsletter archive list. Also it has to display this newsletter because it is the newest supplied news letter. Thanks for all the help and thinking with me MoliK!

Comment: So you can use blog as Lori suggested before. Just open Designer and delete unnecessary parts like left column with calendar icon and date. On the right column can be some WP with recents posts like archive and users can easily add new item (via site or word) that will be automatically on manin column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Page Layouts or preview panes can resolve this.

1. Create  DataView Webpart to with the Bulletin kind of layout (Filter to Show one item on latest date)
2. Create  Date View Webpart to show of list of archives
3. Drag and drop then create a connection on ID